# Using cameraroll for react native on Android

Tags: api, permissions, gallery, react-native, camera-roll

I want to learn and know how to use the camera roll API on Android.

I stayed up all night and didn't sleep. I can use expo to get the camera, and I have seen the cameraroll working fine on iOS. Some people I have seen on Stack Overflow using the cameraroll API from react-native on Android without any third party, but never seen a full code example it's going to be between 30 to 50 lines. I've checked the documentation, and it mentioned Android, but the steps where used for iOS.

Everyone seems to be running away from it, and some people are unclear about it.